# ComsosDB index. Should I exclude it

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In my SQL-CosmosDB I am not using any queries with WHERE condition other than by a partition key + sort by additional field (so a streamId which is a partition key and event position, as I use Cosmos to store my aggragate roots).

I wonder what will happen if I just exclude all paths from indexing in that collection, except maybe keeping the field I am using for sorting.

Comment: It will decrease your index storage, probably save you some RU's also. Be aware that if you change index policy it will affect only new records

Comment: Hi,if my answer helps you,please mark the answer to end it,thanks.

Comment: @JayGong i am upvoting it :)

Comment: @DraganB could you please share a reference where it says changing index policy affects only new records? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexander,according to you requirements,i think you could consider setting the index mode as `None`.Please refer to the explanations in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#indexing-mode).

> If a container's indexing policy is set to None, indexing is
>   effectively disabled on that container. This is commonly used when a
>   container is used as a pure key-value store without the need for
>   secondary indexes. It can also help speeding up bulk insert
>   operations.

Of course,you could choose excluding the root path to selectively include paths that need to be indexed if you have special needs. BTW, as mentioned by @DraganB in the comments,change index policy only affects new records,you could see the statements in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#modifying-the-indexing-policy). So it's better to deliberate at the initial time.

Comment: I can't find confirmation on given link that "change index policy affects only new records". What I do see is "An update to the indexing policy triggers a transformation from the old index to the new one, which is performed online and in place" . Old index = data about existing records.

Comment: @Jay Gong i would also like to hear where did you get that statement from that changing index policy affects only new documents? tnx